# Django: Serializers filtering out undeclared fields

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, mongoengine

Here is my MSV:

**models.py**

```
import mongoengine


class PersonAddressModel(mongoengine.DynamicEmbeddedDocument):
    country = mongoengine.fields.StringField()
    town = mongoengine.fields.StringField()


class PersonModel(mongoengine.DynamicDocument):
    name = mongoengine.fields.StringField()
    age = mongoengine.IntField()
    is_married = mongoengine.fields.BooleanField()
    address = EmbeddedDocumentListField(PersonAddressModel)
```

**serializers.py**

```
from rest_framework_mongoengine import serializers
from .models import PersonInfoModel, PersonAddressModel
import mongoengine


class PersonAddressSerializer(serializers.EmbeddedDocumentSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = PersonAddressModel
        fields = '__all__'


class PersonSerializer(serializers.DynamicDocumentSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = PersonModel
        fields = '__all__'
```

**views.py**

```
from rest_framework_mongoengine import viewsets
from .serializers import PersonSerializer, PersonAddressSerializer
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status
import djongo
from .models import PersonModel


class PersonView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    lookup_field = 'id'
    serializer_class = PersonSerializer

    def create(self, request):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)

        try:
            serializer.is_valid()
            serializer.save()

        except djongo.sql2mongo.SQLDecodeError:
            return Response(
                status=status.HTTP_503_SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE
            )

        return Response(
            status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED
        )
```

I'm sending the following json object:

```
{
    "name": "Helmut",
    "age": 21,
    "is_married": true,
        "address": [{"country": "Germany", "town": "Berlin", "street": "Wolfstraße 1"}]
}
```

However when I check the database I see the following object:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b5e201c540d1c3b7a4491e8"),
    "name" : "Helmut",
    "age" : 21,
    "is_married" : true,
    "address" : [
        {
            "country" : "Germany",
            "town" : "Berlin"
        }
    ]
}
```

That's to say, Helmut's street is missing. I wonder why! My bet is that it has something to do with the serializers but I can't figure out what it is exactly.

**EDIT**

I want both my documents to be dynamic because some jsons may contain fields with unpredictable names and values and I have to save them as well, so I make my both model classes dynamic. However I can expand the `PersonInfoModel` but can't do the same with the `PersonAddressModel`. The `street` field won't show up in the DB (MongoDB). 
On the other hand, I want some of the fields present in the address list to be required.

Comment: Shouldn't you escape the *est-zet*? I'm not convinced this is valid JSON.

Comment: It should be `"Wolfstra\u00dfe 1"`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Well I've tried writing it as "strasse" but alas it doesn't change anything...

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I am able to create correct records from the shell_plus (enhanced version of the django shell) without serializers and stuff but it doesn't work when I use serializers. I'm not 100% sure if it's because of them though...

Comment: What am I doing wrong? I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your **`PersonAddressModel`** you defined only two fields, which are `country` and `town`. Which means, in DB, you defined the schema with those two fields, `street` is not included.
So, change your models to add extra field, as

```
class PersonAddressModel(mongoengine.DynamicEmbeddedDocument):
    country = mongoengine.fields.StringField()
    town = mongoengine.fields.StringField()
    street = mongoengine.fields.StringField()
```

**UPDATE**
If your `address` field is dynamic and it's a dict like field, then use [**`mongoengine.fields.DictField()`**](http://docs.mongoengine.org/apireference.html#mongoengine.fields.DictField) as,

```
import mongoengine


class PersonModel(mongoengine.DynamicDocument):
    name = mongoengine.fields.StringField()
    age = mongoengine.IntField()
    is_married = mongoengine.fields.BooleanField()
    address = mongoengine.fields.DictField()
```

**Update-2**
You can do a [`field level validation`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#field-level-validation) in **`PersonSerializer`** as,

```
from rest_framework_mongoengine import serializers
from rest_framework import serializers as drf_serializer


class PersonSerializer(serializers.DynamicDocumentSerializer):
    def validate_address(self, address):
        required_fields = ['street', 'country']
        if not all([True for field in required_fields if field in address]):
            raise drf_serializer.ValidationError('some required fields are missing')
        return address

    class Meta:
        model = PersonModel
        fields = '__all__'
```

Since `rest_framework_mongoengine` doesnt have a `ValidationError` class, we using `DRF's ValidationError class`

**UPDATE-3**
Inorder to raise validation error, you have to pass `True` to `.is_valid()` (reff doc - [Raising an exception on invalid data](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#raising-an-exception-on-invalid-data))method, as

```
class PersonView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    lookup_field = 'id'
    serializer_class = PersonSerializer

    def create(self, request):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)

        try:
            serializer.is_valid(True) # Change is here <<<<
            serializer.save()

        except djongo.sql2mongo.SQLDecodeError:
            return Response(
                status=status.HTTP_503_SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE
            )

        return Response(
            status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED
        )
```

Comment: Oh sorry for not mentioning it in the question, but I want both my documents to be dynamic, meaning I want to dynamically add extra fields when needed cos in each json data may differ, however there are a few fields that are required. But I want the docs to be dynamic, that's why `PersonMode`l and `PersonAddressModel` inherit from `DynamicDocument` and `DynamicEmbeddedDocument` accordingly.

Comment: The problem is that in a dynamic document all types of fields may appear, for example if I add an extra field to my json (`kids` for instance) and post it to the DB it will save it. In other words sometimes I don't know what fields may be present so I make the doc dynamic, it works for the `PersonModel` but for some reason it does not for the `PersonAddressModel`. If I try to add an extra field to it, it doesn't show up in the DB...

Comment: Did you tried with `DictField` in `PersonModel` as i mentioned in UPDATE?

Comment: Yeah it works but  is it possible to control the dict fields? I made the address field embedded because this way I can make some of the fields required but with a dict field it seems like any fields may be added.

Comment: oops.. I was thought it could be done via `child` attribute. I found that somewhere on the internet. but, now I couldn't

Comment: But, you could write custom validation over `address` dict field

Comment: see my **Update-2** section

Comment: I tried it, but it happens that mongoengine's `serializers` doesn't have `ValidationError` member and `super()`  doesn't have `validate_address` member.
These are the errors I'm getting. Thank you for trying to help. I will be back in an hour.

Comment: it appears that mongoengine `serializers` are in a way different from the django rest frame work ones.

Comment: try to comment out `super()` method

Comment: I've modified my **Update-2**, please do try it

Comment: Yep, I've just tried, actually, as far as I understand the condition should be
`if not all([True if field in address else False for field in required_fields]):`
or I could possibly iterate over the required fields and check if all of them are in the address field. But in both cases it errors out with `AssertionError: You cannot call .save() on a serializer with invalid data.` Which is reasonable cos I'm trying to save invalid data

Comment: So perhaps yes, I think it does work as expected now. Thank you a lot!!!

Comment: But still I don't quite understand why the validation error is not raised

Comment: Change `serializer.is_valid()` to `serializer.is_valid(True)` in your view

Comment: Yeah now the expected error is raised but is it correct to pass `True` to the `is_valid` method. I mean it looks just terrible...

Comment: I have add the   drf doc link to the **update-3** section. It's not terrible, it must be `True` if you want to raise the validation error

Comment: Aaah it seems like it's the same as `raise_exception=True`, yeah I didn't see it at once. Thanks one more time. And please change the `if not any([True for field in required_fields if field in address]):` to the correct one.

Comment: Whats the problem with that line?  I don't find any problem

Comment: `if not any([True for field in required_fields if field in address]):` if one of the required fields is missing it will just add `True` to the list, then `any` will check if any of the list element is equal to True, so basically it will always yield True unless all the required fields are missing. All the required fields should be present.

Comment: Oh.. my bad... changed `any()` with `all()`. Try it

Comment: it's okay. Even though I think `else False` is necessary. 
In other workds this one works for me
`[True if field in address else False for field in required_fields]`

Comment: If you don't mind my asking, do you have any ideas why my initial approach doesn't work (with embedded doc , serializers etc)?

Comment: It's.simply because, you didn't added a `field`. According to Relational Database, you can only  add values to fields which are already defined. I assume the same logic behind in you case, *NoSQL* like MongoDB